# Automating dataframe extracting from different workbook of excel file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the script that I am using

For reading file

```
excel = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')
```

To get the different sheets I am using

```
excel.sheet_names
```

Let say the sheet_names are [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]. I am parsing each sheet_name to extract the data like this

```
df_A = excel.parse(sheet_name = 'A')
df_B = excel.parse(sheet_name = 'B')
```

Need to automate all dataframe creation in one go ? Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps will be more efficient to store each sheet as a key in a dictionary, with ```excel_sheets = pd.read_excel(file_fullpath, sheetname=None)```, and access each sheet as a dataframe like this: ```excel_sheets['A']```, ```excel_sheets['B']```, instead of storing all different sheets as separate DF's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you it would be better to use loop with locals() see my code below.
the reason why "locals()[a]" is used instead of a directly is that if you use "a=pd.read_excel()", only variable a will has recent sheet of data.xlsx, H sheet, and there would be no df_A, df_B, ... df_H variables

```
for i in pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx').sheet_names:
 
    print(i)
    a='df_'+i
    locals()[a]=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=i, header=0)
    print(locals()[a])
```