# Opening Exported Excel File without writer.save() in Python

Tags: python, pandas, export

I am exporting data from python to excel using pandas in python. I am using a loop to iteratively create data frames and update the excel file.

I cannot use the `writer.save()` function in the middle of the loop because the next iteration has trouble opening the file to update it. The error is something about trying to open a closed file.

But if I use `writer.save()` at the end, and there is some error in the middle of the loop, then although an excel file is created (and updated until the error hits), I cannot open it because Windows cannot recognize the extension. This is preventing me from looking at the data that is being generated in the incomplete excel file.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: im not sure if this is what you meant...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622226/16478699

Comment: @sanzo213 but even in this process, if I write something in the file instead of reading, I will have to save it, correct? Then the problem persists, no?